# emberJS mixin super override

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, ember.js, mixins

How can i override a mixin but still keep the old mixin functionality.

I have a mixin that uses `beforeModel`, and have a route:

```
App.PlayRoute = Ember.Route.extend("beforeModelMixin", {
    beforeModel: {
        // Here i want to have mixin beforeModel functionality as well as my own hook.
    }
}
```

Above example `beforeModelMixin` gets overriden and doesn't work anymore, because i defined `beforeModel` again.

Is that possible?